# React Quill Custom Ordered list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

Is it possible to make a custom ordered list in react quill, where the first level is capitalised letters and the second level is lower case roman numerals.
e.g.

```
A. first level
   i. second level
   ii. second level
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, simply override the default quill styles

```
.ql-editor li {
 // your custom styles here
}
```